# Как отправить сообщение видимое одному человеку? discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Я ранее уже задавал этот вопрос но так и не получил на него нормального ответа, скорее всего меня не поняли.

**Как отправить такое сообщение в discord.py?:**
[image: вот такое сообщение]

UPD:

В данном случае мне надо отправить это сообщение в **on_raw_reaction_add**:

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  global not_active
  global post_id
  print('---Зафиксирована реакция---')
  if payload.message_id == post_id:
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    print(f'-----{user.name} отметился-----')
    not_active.remove(user.mention)
    config['DEFAULT']['not_active'] = f'{" ".join(not_active)}'
    with open('settings.ini', 'w') as configfile:
      config.write(configfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

В функции `send()` включите параметр `ephemeral=True`. Это пришлёт именно такое сообщение. Пример:

```
await ctx.send('Привет!', ephemeral=True)
```

UPD:

Через некоторое тестирование выяснилось, что discord не позволяет отвечать 'невидимыми' сообщениями на обычные комманды. Для slash-комманд и кнопок все работает прекрасно.

Пример кода:

```
import asyncio
import discord

from discord.ext import commands


class Handlers(commands.Cog):


    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):

        self.bot = bot


    @commands.hybrid_command('test')
    async def test(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        await ctx.send('test', ephemeral=True)

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='!',
    intents=discord.Intents.all(),
    case_insensitive=True,
)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()


asyncio.run(client.add_cog(Handlers(client)))
client.run('token')
```

(Код грустный, тут только для демонстрации примера)

Обратите внимание на версию discord.py! Для этого примера `discord == 2.1.0`.

Comment: То-есть это сообщения увидит только тот, кто использовал команду?

Comment: `TypeError: Messageable.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'`

Comment: Привет! Покажи ка мне код отправки сообщения, может быть что-нибудь надумаю. Желательно еще укажи версию discord.py

Comment: если есть дискорд, то лучше там продолжить: `QuL1ux#2902`

Comment: вы будете продолжать помогать?

Comment: Да, но лучше тут... Версия библиотеки то какая?

Comment: discord-py==2.1.0

Comment: Странно, должно работать в этой ситуации. Вы, может быть, отдельно сообщение создаёте? Можете прикрепить ваш код к вопросу?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Вы ещё тут или как?